# Is a narrow beam of light inconsistent with light as waves?

Tags: visible-light

Apparently light can be sent out in very narrow beams.  That is easy to understand as particles.  However, I don’t know of any way to send waves as a narrow beam.  Of course I’m thinking of things like waves in water.  Waves in water could be narrow with linear fronts to the waves if it is contained between 2 walls, but as soon as it exits the walls it will spread out in circular form.  What’s the deal with light?  How can light as waves go in a narrow beam?

Comment: You can have a narrow beam of sound waves. [See this link](http://phys.org/news/2009-06-sonic-boom-world-lasers.htmll).

Comment: [What is EM radiation, photon, EM wave](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90646/what-is-the-relation-between-electromagnetic-wave-and-photon/253957#253957)

Comment: the link for narrow beam of sound waves doesn't work

Comment: @HuckRorick: there was an extra 'l' in the URL. [Try this revised link](http://phys.org/news/2009-06-sonic-boom-world-lasers.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a beam of light that is a millimeter wide (1/25th of an inch), then its width is approximately 2000 times the wavelength (since the wavelength of visible light is ~400-700 billionths of a meter, depending on color).

Due to diffraction, that means that the beam will spread out by roughly 1 unit for every 2000 units it travels: send the beam down the length of a football field and it will be narrower than a football.

Water waves typically are much closer to the size of the gap they pass through (say, ocean waves through the mouth of a harbor) and so they spread out a lot more.